# Squish for Windows keep inspecting the whole application window

Tags: python, automated-tests, squish

I've just moved from using Squish for Web to Squish for Windows to automation test a window application, and i'm having this issue. When i tried to record and playback testcases, Squish keep inspecting only the whole application window instead of inspecting specific objects. For each event (e.g. clickButton()), Squish just simply pointed to the button's location on the application window and clicked on it (area).
Here is an example testscript that Squish generated for my app:

```
# test.py
startApplication("\"AppX\"")
mouseClick(waitForObject(names.AppX_Window), 554, 782, MouseButton.PrimaryButton)
mouseClick(waitForObject(names.AppX_Window), 560, 828, MouseButton.PrimaryButton)

# names.py
AppX_Window = {"text": "App X", "type": "Window"}
```

So i decided to give a try on another window application which is Paint, and Squish worked beautifully. It inspected each specific button that i clicked and declared every single of them in names.py file.
Here is an example testscript that Squish generated for Paint:

```
# test.py
startApplication("mspaint")
clickButton(waitForObject(names.pencil_Button))
clickButton(waitForObject(names.fill_with_color_Button))

# names.py
pencil_Button = {"text": "Pencil", "type": "Button"}
fill_with_color_Button = {"text": "Fill with color", "type": "Button"}
```

**Is there anyway for squish to hook into specific objects on my application the same way it hooked into paint's?**
(I'm completely new to Squish, StackOverFlow and writing in English so if anything is inappropriate or annoyed, please be kind enough to let me know, thank you so so much!)

Comment: It should do that in general. The fact that it does not means that there is Squish specific a problem and you should contact the vendor's technical support to help with this.

Comment: @BaoTran What program did this occur with? Is the source code available? Being able to see the source code would help a lot with debugging the issue.